# Jquery trigger click event 2nd time not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css

I am trying to trigger a menu that opens up when the page tour starts and closes it when the page tour closes.
Below is the code

```html
step2.on("show", () => {
            if (!Feature) {
                tour.complete();
            }
            else {
                toggleHelpMenu()
            }
        });
        tour.on('complete', () => {
                toggleHelpMenu()
            this.dashboard.pageTourSwitchOrientationStep(this.currentProgressStepId);
        });
        tour.on('cancel', () => {
            this.dashboard.pageTourSwitchOrientationStep(this.currentProgressStepId);
        });
        function toggleHelpMenu() {
            $("#vFooterContentSupportEmailArea").trigger('click');
        }
```

at step 9, when the tour step is open, I can see click event triggers successfully.
However when tour completes at '**tour.on('complete')**', click event is not triggering.

Comment: where do you trigger the `complete` event for `tour`?

Comment: it triggers itself when the page tour ends. I can see that toogleHelpMenu hits but does not trigger a click event.

Comment: @GrafiCode, it triggers when I click the end tour button. Also, I am using the shepherd page tour